# Convert string to number and multiple it inside a object in the response array - Angular 7

Tags: angular

I have an observable that reviving an Array of objects. Inside those objects there is a value of type string that i want to convert to a number and  multiple him before the subscription.
How can i do it?

My try

```
getList() {
        return this.http.get(BACK_END_URL).pipe(
            map((response: any) => response.upload_date * 1000),
            finalize(() => this.interactionService.setSpinnerStatus.next(false)),
        ).subscribe(response => {
            console.log(response)
        });
}
```

Objects

```
[
    {
        "_id": string,
        "name": string,
        "upload_date": string
    }
]
```

Comment: Try to use the parseInt method: parseInt(response.upload_date, 10) * 1000

Comment: It's not really clear from your question what you are looking for. If you wish to transform the result emitted by an Observable you should indeed use `Observable.pipe(map( data => { return new_data; } )).subscribe(...)`. Also know that the types you speak of are TypeScript types, they're only used by the TypeScript compiler. At runtime the types behave like in JavaScript where you can do `+"55" + 5` yielding `60` as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the spread operator and modify the property you want:

```
getList() {
    return this.http.get(BACK_END_URL).pipe(
        map((response: any) => {
          return {
              ...response,
              upload_date: Number(response.upload_date) * 1000
          };
        }),
        finalize(() => this.interactionService.setSpinnerStatus.next(false)),
    ).subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response)
    });
}
```